# Prove that [x/y] is a primitive recursive function

Tags: functions, computability

Prove that [x/y] is a primitive recursive function using this theorem:
If $g(x_1,...,x_n)$ is primitive recursive, then $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum^{x_n}_{i=0}g(x_1,...,x_{n-1},i)$ is also a primitive recursive function.
I've tried, but I couldn't come up with an idea.

Comment: How did you define primitive recursive functions?

Comment: $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a primitive recursive function if $f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)=g(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ and 
$f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},y+1)=h(x_1,...,y,f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},y))$.
g and h are primitive recursive functions

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I thought that you had an issue with proving the theorem, not that $[x/y]$ is primitive recursive.

Comment: Do you use [x/y] to denote substitution or is it some other concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right]$ is the integer part of the division of $x$ and $y$, and that $x, y \in \mathbb{N} \cup\{0\}$ then let us define $\left[ \frac{x}{0} \right] = x$.

Remark: In discrete math and computer science, it seems quite usual to include $0$ in the natural numbers. Also, note that this function is similar to the floor function.

To prove the assertion that $\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right]$ is primitive recursive, consider the following equivalences:

$$  \left[ \frac{x}{y} \right]=z \iff \left(y=0 \land x=z \right) \lor \left( y \neq 0 \land z \leq \frac{x}{y} \lt z+1 \right)$$

$$\iff \left(y=0 \land x=z \right) \lor \left( y \neq 0 \land zy \leq {x} \lt (z+1)y \space \right) $$
$$\iff \left(y=0 \land x=z \right) \lor \left( y \neq 0 \land z \space\text{is the smallest natural number such that} \space {x} \lt (z+1)y \space \right) $$

Additionally, note that $\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right] \leq x$.Thus, we can define the function using the [bounded minimisation operator](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Bounded_Minimization) :

$$\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right] = \mu z \leq x\left[ (y=0 \land x=z) \lor (y \neq 0 \land x<(z+1)y) \space \right]$$

Therefore the function $\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right]$ has been constructed by the bounded minimisation operator of primitive recursive functions and relations. It follows from the definition of a primitive recursive function that $\left[ \frac{x}{y} \right]$ is primitive recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are referring to integer division.

You can define $\lceil x/y \rceil$ by primitive recursion, like this:

$h(x,y,0) = 0$ , 
$h(x,y,t+1) = \begin{cases}
    h(x,y,t) + 1 & \mbox{$x - t\cdot y \geq 0$}\\
    h(x,y,t)& \mbox{ow.}
    \end{cases}
$

And so, $\lceil x/y \rceil = h(x,y,x)$

I used that $+,\cdot,-,\geq$ are all primitive recursive (with $-$ restricted to natural numbers in the canonical way) and that $\lceil x/0 \rceil = 0$.